# Locking QGIS and parent forms

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt, qt

I am trying to make a plugin for QGIS.
This plugin has lots of forms and based on the condition the form calls a child Form. The following is an example

[image]

I am using PyQt for creating forms. I want the Parrent and QGIS not be accessible(totally locked) while the CHILD is active.
and the user either can select or close the child.

Can someone guide me on how can it be done?

Comment: Hint: the term you want to look for is modal.
For more help, please write what you have tried so far and paste some minimal code example.

Comment: yes you are right, I did some search and added
        self.selectionList_dlg.setModal(True)
to my code and it works as I expected.